# Rails g Controller AWS S3 Syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, rubygems

I'm new to using rails with aws s3 and want am gaining experience through tutorials. I'm stuck on generating the controller and views because of a files syntax, This is my process.

```
rails g controller Songs index upload delete
```

Below is the output of the command :

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223:in `class_eval': /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: `@@{' is not allowed as a class variable name (SyntaxError)
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:223: syntax error, unexpected end-of-inputunless defined? @@{:instance_writer=>true}
```

Is it as simple to deleting '@@{' in the file ? That doesn't seem logical to me because I haven't done any editing to any of these rb files.

Please help me understand this more.

Thanks.

Comment: Please let us know which gem and gem version you used for `amazon s3`. also let us know your `rails version`.

Comment: the gem you are trying is really old. https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/tree/master/lib/aws/s3 
look at this issue -https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/issues/98